# Scala list pattern matching in value declaration

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching, tuples

Assuming the following list of four tuples:

```
> def getList = List( (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) )
```

I want to parse it into three sections in new values declaration like this - **the last tuple** `(l1,l2)`, **the penultimate tuple** `(p1,p2)` and **the rest of the list** `rest`.

Moreover, I'd like to pattern-match the tuples as well. Example:

```
> val (rest :: (p1, p2) :: (l1, l2) ) = getList
rest = List( (1,2), (3,4) )
p1 = 5
p2 = 6
l1 = 7
l2 = 8
```

The expected output does not work because `::` expects a list as its right-side argument. I tried several different possibilities such as `:::` with `List` wrapper. However, I haven't managed to achieve the goal.

Is it even possible? I don't want to reverse the list - instead, I'm looking for an elegant solution that is applicable to value declaration (thus no `match` please). I hope in one-line solution.

Edit: Scala code runner version 2.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `:+` matcher object:

```
val rest :+ ((p1, p2)) :+ ((l1, l2))  = getList
```

It's [the part of standard library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.$colon$plus$) since scala 2.10

For previous version you redefine it yourself using [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/SeqExtractors.scala#L1)

Comment: not really :-/ `error: not found: value :+` and `error: recursive value x$1 needs type`

Comment: @petrbel What is the version of scala library?

Comment: @petrbel it's available in 2.10